# Solve for x without using the quadratic formula

Tags: integration, quadratics, random-functions

Some context: I'm doing an inverse transformation method where I have the probability density function split in three parts. The first part is:

$$
f_1:\frac{x-6}{8}
$$

For $ 6 < x < 8 $.

I know by integrating $ f_1 $ that the range goes from  $ 0 $ to $ 0.25 $.

So now I'm trying solve for $ x$.

$$
u=\int^x_6\frac{x-6}{8}dx
$$

Where $ u $ is in the range $ [0, 0.25] $ (and is taken as a random variable with uniform distribution).

I remember that the professor was able to solve for $ x $ without doing quadratic formula. Because I have an exam tomorrow and it will take long to solve (and it will be a lot harder if I have a greater degree polynomial), I need to remember. Anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

Set

$y = x - 6; \tag{1}$

then

$u = \int_6^x \dfrac{x -  6}{8} dx = \int_0^y \dfrac{y}{8}dy$
$ = \dfrac{1}{8}\int_0^y ydy = \dfrac{y^2}{16}; \tag{2}$

thus

$y^2 = 16u, \tag{3}$

or

$y = 4\sqrt{u}. \tag{4}$

Not quite the quadratic formula!

Taking it one step further,

$x = y + 6 = 4\sqrt{u} + 6. \tag{5}$

Comment: My calculus might be growing mold =S. May I ask, why did you change the lower bound to 0 instead of 6?

Comment: Because with $y = x - 6$, $[6, x] \mapsto [0, y]$.  Standard change of variables stuff!

Comment: Guess it did work!  Thanks for the "acceptance"!  Remember, the trick works for $\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{(x - \alpha)}{\gamma}dx$, in case you see it on your exam!  Best of luck.  Cheers!

Comment: : ) Yes, I more or less figured out the rules for using that. I think it also worked with higher degree polynomials (doesn't it?). You have potentially saved me from dying in my exam tomorrow... Now I have to go back to studying queueing models :(

Comment: What I meant to say was that the trick should work for $\int_\alpha^\beta \dfrac{(x - \alpha)^n}{\gamma}dx$ as well.  Anyway, again, best of luck!